# Suggestions for wireframing / low-fi prototyping tools

Tags: tools, interaction, wireframing

my experience with wireframing or low fidelity prototyping tools is pretty bad.

All of the tools is used seemed extremly time-consuming and limited in terms of creating.
You always have a fixed set of elements to choose from, fixed layouts and always a drag & drop system which makes it really slow. 
Furthermore I couldn´t find any tool that works good or rather fluent and intuitive on a tablet.

I have tried balsamiq mockups, omnigraffle, axure, pencil project, mockflow, wireframe.cc and lucidchart.

I´m normally starting with sketches, mind maps, etc. to visualize the concept first. Afterwards I want to transform it into digital wireframes or low-fi prototypes which I want to use for early prototyping to get feedback about the structure, the logic the navigation and the app in general.The tool doesn´t need to have prototyping features, since I can do this with inVision or proto.io, but I need a quick solution, thats easy to work with and if possible availble for tablets

Did you experience the same problem or am I alone? 
Can anybody please recommend me tools that are different and could fit my needs?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You didn't tell us with what you start and what you want to get.  That missing information could help us to help you.

Comment: Yeah that´s right, I´m sorry. 
I´m normally starting with sketches, mind maps, etc. to visualize the concept first. 
Afterwards I want to transform it into digital wireframes or low-fi prototypes which I want to use for early prototyping to get feedback about the structure, the logic the navigation and the app in general without visual aspects. 

The tool doesn´t need to have prototyping features, since I can do this with inVision or proto.io, but I need a quick solution, thats easy to work with and if possible availble for tablets

Comment: please edit your question to include that

Answer (score 2):

in my experience it is best to draw these up using good old pencil and paper. I find that using a digital tool too much really doesn't get to the core of the wireframe and usually end up with the same result for each website.

- Gather your notes
- Grab a pen and pencil
- Draw out some ideas on paper
- Once happy and have a clear view then use a tool like Balsamiq.

This should speed up and have a more defined approach to your wireframes.

Comment: Thanks chris, 
this is what I´m doing right as this is the best way for me to explore all possiblities. 

But when I converted an original sketch into a digital wireframe and test it, I want a simple solution for implementing new visions, changes etc.

I find it quite cumbersome to go back to pen and paper, so I stick with digital and I´m back at the original problem again.

Comment: Then I would say use the tools which you know best. I personally don't use a wireframe program for the reasons you said above. I usually use Illustrator with a neutral grey colour scheme, I know then if I want a random shape I can just draw it out.

Comment: That´s a good idea. 
But don´t you then tend to skip to wireframing part and directly jump into color & details etc. ?

Comment: Adding colour is not too bad. I try and keep in the mindset though that this is the layout and whats going on but not exactly where they are going on.
This is a good reference of what Illustrator can do for wireframing - https://dribbble.com/shots/1750628-Late-night-wire-n?list=searches&offset=14

Its kind of a middle. A comfortable middle.

Comment: Thanks for this Chris!
Seems to be a widespread solution (just googled it) and I will see if it fits for me.
Does Illustrator have the ability to export styles/structure to CSS/HTML ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the answer to that.

Comment: Never mind, 
I will discover it!